# Is there a way to integrate an Expo app with firebase dynamic links without detaching?

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-dynamic-links

Is there a way to integrate an Expo app with firebase dynamic links without detaching.

Comment: Anyone trying to create the universal link - https://germavinsmoke.hashnode.dev/how-to-create-universal-link-in-expo-using-firebase-dynamic-link

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you need to **create** new dynamic links on the fly you could use [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest) to do it. In the much more likely scenario that you only need your app to **open** Firebase's dynamic links, you don't need to do anything other than configuring your Expo App to handle universal links (ie: deeplinks using http/https).

The checklist is something like this:

## 1. Configure your app.json

For Android, add the `intentFilters` property to your `android` property:

```js
"android": {
  "intentFilters": [
    {
      "action": "VIEW",
      "data": [
        {
          "scheme": "https",
          "host": "<your-domain>",
          "pathPrefix": "/"
        },
      ],
      "category": [
        "BROWSABLE",
        "DEFAULT"
      ],
      "autoVerify": true // required to work on newer android versions
    }
  ]
]
```

For iOS, add the `associatedDomains` property to `ios`:

```js
"ios": {
  "associatedDomains": ["applinks:<your-domain>"]
}
```

## 2. Configure your domain to allow links from it to be handled by the apps

Android and iOS will allow your app to open links from your domain if you serve a configuration file from a specific location:

Android: `https://<your-domain>/.well-known/assetlinks.json`

iOS: `https://<your-domain>/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`

`assetlinks.json` will look something like this:

```js
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "<android-package-name>",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["<your-sha256-certificate-fingerprints>"]
  }
}]
```

And the `apple-app-site-association` like this:

```js
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "<your-team-id>.<ios-bundle-identifier>",
                "paths": [ "*" ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You can read more about these files [here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12-SW4).

To obtain the SHA256 fingerprints of your app’s signing certificate you can use the keytool:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore <your-key-file>
```

After you enter your keystore password, it will print many of the keystore information including the SHA256 fingerprints.

If your site is hosted on Firebase both `assetlinks.json` and `apple-app-site-association` can be generated automatically if you create the Apps on your Firebase's project. Otherwise, just put these files on the root of your domain.

## 3. Create a Firebase dynamic link

I think this is step is mostly self explanatory but just a few notes:

1. Set up your short URL link: in the end you will have / that you send to your users
2. Set up your Dynamic Link: here you define your deelink (the link you want your app to handle)
3. Define link behavior for iOS: you mostly likely want to click on 'Open the deep link in your iOS App' and select your App from the list (if you haven't yet, create one App for each platform on your project)
4. Define link behavior for Android: same as previous but with a few more options to select
5. Configure (or not) campaign tracking and you're done.

**Remember that you always should test your deeplinks by clicking instead of by entering directly on the browser. You may send the link to yourself on the WhatsApp or put on some notes app, for example.**

Others resources that might be helpful:

- https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/linking/
- https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/

Comment: Do I need to have an App Store ID in order for this to work?

Comment: No, just your Team ID and App Bundle Identifier.

Comment: Thanks for your response! But, it should only work when you build a standalone app, right?

Comment: No problem. Exactly.

Comment: Great answer! I'm also concerned about link open reports (first open and re-opens data firebase provides). Do you know a way of reporting those events? I'll be using Analytics, but it would be nicer to have it working more closely as normal.

Comment: Did this work? I am still trying to implement this.. But it seems I have to eject from expo because I am not able to pass params through the url like: url?param1=abs

Comment: is it really necessary to re-submit an app to the app store in order to add this functionality? Is it possible to add this to an existing app, without having to go through an app store update?

Comment: @Marchingband you have to resubmit for this

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Pedro Andrade's instructions:

**1.)** Firebase requires the following details under your *app > project settings* for dynamic links to work.

- Android: SHA 256 (App signing key certificate fingerprint) - this can be retrieved via `play store > your app > App Integrity > SHA 256`
- iOS: App ID Prefix (Team ID): `developer.apple.com > Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles > your app id > App ID Prefix`

Surprisingly, these are mentioned almost nowhere in the docs, but do come up in stackoverflow results and other answers when googling errors that debugging preview links result in:

```
Android app '<bundle id>' lacks SHA256. AppLinks is not enabled for the app. Learn more.
iOS app '<bundle id>' lacks App ID Prefix. UniversalLinks is not enabled for the app. Learn more.
```

You can view debugging preview links by adding `?d=1` to your dynamic links.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/debug

**2.)** Even if you use a page.link-style domain provided by firebase for your dynamic links, your associatedDomain/intentFilter domains in app.json should still be your actual domain

i.e if you're generating `my-app.page.link` shortLinks, that are dynamic links to `my-app.com`, you should use `my-app.com` in `app.json`

Comment: Is my domain `mydomain.com` OR the subdomain that will handle the link i.e. `links.mydomain.com`? In my case, my website is hosted elsewhere and I want to keep it that way. In order to handle dynamic links, I added a subdomain i.e. `links` that is hosted on Firebase. So, I'm not sure which I need to use for domain. Currently, I keep getting a 401 error and I'm trying to see if the domain may be a part of the problem.

Comment: this is incorrect you should use the page.link url

Answer (score 1):

Pedro Andrade's solution works! Partially...

Explaining:

1. You must **NOT** add your dynamic link domain in intentFilters and associatedDomains, because it makes the app to open the link directly in the app, so, the dynamic link is not processed and you don't have access to the link generated by the dynamic link.
2. It works partially because of this: the dynamic link needs to be opened by the browser (chrome or safari) before being opened in the app.

Example: Open `"<your-domain>.page.link/XLSj"` in browser, browser will direct to generated link: `"<your-domain>.com/params/54"` to configured deep link.

I don't know any other way to 'read' the dynamic link by expo in managed workflow.

Comment: if you use expo linking you can access the url in the app whenever it's opened via dynamic link