# Firebase dynamic links and Expo

Tags: android, firebase, expo, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm developing an Expo app and I'm using Firebase dynamic links in order to open the reset password link inside the app. Everything is working perfectly, except that when I test the app on Android, it gives me the option to open the link either in my app or in Chrome. Is there any way I can force the link to always open in my app without giving options to the user?

Comment: how did you add firebase dynamic links to an expo app? do you have any manual for that?

Comment: @user1974368 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62415111/is-there-a-way-to-integrate-an-expo-app-with-firebase-dynamic-links-without-deta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening a web link on Android device will observe the user's preferences for how they want to open that link.  The link can't somehow override the user's preference.

If you're writing Android code to programmatically open a link, you have some [options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013416/is-there-any-way-in-android-to-force-open-a-link-to-open-in-chrome), but for general purpose web use, the user's preference is always honored.